# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in BST

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, insertion

i have checked the code like million times but this error won't go please help, it is the program for creating Binary search tree...
i am using VS Code for compilation

```
  typedef struct node node;
node *newNode(int key){
    node *temp=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->info=key;
    temp->left=temp->right=NULL;
    return temp; }
void inorder(node *root){
    if(root!=NULL){
        inorder(root->left);
        printf("%d\t",root->info);
        inorder(root->right); } }

node *Insert(node *root,int key){
    if(root=NULL){ return newNode(key);}
    if(key<root->info){    
       root->left = Insert(root->left,key); }
    else if(key>root->info){    
       root->right = Insert(root->right,key);  }
    return root;
}
int main(){
    int n,v;
    node *root=NULL;
    printf("enter the no of values you wanna enter");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int i = 0;
    while(i<=n){
         scanf("%d\n",&v);
         root=Insert(root,v);
         i++;
    }
    inorder(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's that: `if(root=NULL)`? I think should be ` if(root==NULL)`.

Comment: Your code formatting is inconsistent & all over the place. Please adopt a more conventional one, if you expect other programmers to read your code. I can't be bother to decipher this & count all the braces...

Comment: "assignment inside if" is commonly caught by warnings. You should be compiling with warnings enabled and fixing all warnings before running anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Sir Jo Black and dratenik said, the bug is an "assignment inside if" in the line

```
if(root=NULL){ return newNode(key);}
```

This assigns NULL to root and causes the condition to be considered false. So, the program continues to the following line and attempts to read `root->info`, which is a null pointer dereference and causes the segmentation fault.

It is a good idea to enable warnings (and to pay attention to what they say). For debugging memory-related bugs, an excellent tool is AddressSanitizer (ASan). See [AddressSanitizer (ASan) for Windows with MSVC](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/addresssanitizer-asan-for-windows-with-msvc/) about how to install and use it in Visual Studio.

Comment: @SamarthShinde If this solved your problem, don't forget to "accept the answer".